# MVC .Net Core 2.0 | Query SQL Server database and return results in grid-view

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm learning .net Core 2.0 at the moment and have built a fairly simple web application, however, I've not done much with the 'Model' aspect of the MVC structure.

I have a test SQL Server running on a separate Windows Server VM which I would like to bring into the application.

Essentially this database contains a table with a list of people. I just want to display that data in a gridview on one of my application pages, with a simple query;

i.e. `SELECT title, forename, surname, address_string, telnum FROM people;`

I would like some advice, either code or a link to a good resource / tutorial which walks me through how to do this.

Bear in mind that I am learning MVC after a long time out of web development, my experience of this previously has just been to bind a data table to a gridview in ASP web forms.

Thanks.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Was I supposed to know the answer before I asked the question?

Comment: Don't worry, the developers at stackoverflow are very specific and don't understand that some are just learning, I gave you a top grade because someone wrongly rated you. Good luck! By the way, I'm also learning and the question is helpful, thanks too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MVC, there is no gridview to bind to and no viewstates unlike in webforms. For the model part, it is best to expand that to use view models which is separate from the model/domain model.

Think of view models as something that gives you more control to shape the data that comes from the database. Note that in the `PersonViewModel` below, I opted to exclude the `PersonID` mapped to the table's primary key. I also added a field that returns the person's full name (lastname, firstname). These changes are isolated to the view model only and does not affect the domain model.

Model (which can be mapped to the database table/columns):

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ForeName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string TelNum { get; set; }
    public string AddressString { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel (which essentially gives you more control on what to show on the page):

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FullName 
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}, {1}", this.LastName, this.FirstName); }
    }
}
```

Controller code (where you can transfer the values of the fields from the domain model to the view model. For simplicity, I've chosen to assign the field values manually but there are tools like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) that simplifies this):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // returns List<Person> from the database
    var peopleList = datasource.GetPeople();

    var peopleVM = new List<PersonViewModel>();

    //create a list of PersonViewModels
    foreach (person in peopleList)
    {
        var personVM = new PersonViewModel()
        {
             FirstName = person.ForeName;
             LastName = person.SurName;
             Address = person.AddressString;
             Title = person.Title;
             Telephone = person.TelNum;                 
        };
        peopleVM.Add(personVM);
    }

    return View(peopleVM);
}
```

View (where you'd display the view model. There is really no concept of "binding" and viewstates out of the box like in webforms and not much built-in controls like gridviews/listviews unless you are going to use MVC extensions like [these](https://demos.devexpress.com/mvcxgridviewdemos/)):

```
@model List<Namespace.Models.PersonViewModel>

<table>
    @foreach (person in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>person.FullName</td>
            <td>person.Title</td>
            <td>person.Telephone</td>
            <td>person.Address</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

As for links for good resources, you can't go wrong with [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) and [this one too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be starting with the Microsoft Docs on .Net Core 2.0 and Entity Framework Core here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

To summarize, you'll use .Net Core as your MVC layer, and you'll leverage Entity Framework Core as your ORM (basically your database interaction model).  Once you get acquainted with EF Core, you may find you actually need the older "full" Entity Framework, and here's a short summary on the differences: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features

There are also other non-MS ORMs out there, but I'd stick with the Microsoft stack to get started since it was generally all designed to work together and Microsoft produces good end-to-end tutorials.

Once you work your way through the first tutorial, you may also want to consider looking into a client-side library for handling your grid, searching, sorting, etc.  DataTables is a popular one that works well with JQuery and Bootstrap (which are in the default MVC template) out of the box (https://datatables.net/), and you'll also find good support for it on this site.